# Adding cusparse dependency in meson build

Tags: meson-build, cusparse

I am building an application with meson that uses NVIDIA cuSPARSE library. Currently, I have to hard code the cusparse version information into the dependency as shown below:

```
cusparse_dep = dependency('cusparse-10.3', version : '>=10.0')
```

The problem is that unless the version number is exact (cusparse-10.3), meson seems not to find the dependency although version >= 10.0 is mentioned. What is the best way to declare this dependency in meson so that even if the exact version number is not mentioned, meson can find it?

Thanks

Comment: How have you installed `cusparse`?

Comment: I am running my code on a cluster. I load the cuda environment module before compiling/executing the code.

Comment: It seams that on your environment, your dependency is installed by `cusparse-10.3` name. You can check that with `pkg-config` or `cmake`.